# Value Forbidden of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

When I try to get historical data from yahoo like this:

```
private fun getStockHistoricalData(){
    val queue = VolleySingleton.getInstance(this)
    val query = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/AAPL?period1=1635962336&period2=1667498336&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true"
    val request = StringRequest( Request.Method.GET,query,
        { response ->
            println("response = $response")
        },
        { error ->
            println("Error ${parseVolleyError(error)}")
        }
    )
    request.setShouldCache(false)
    queue.addToRequestQueue(request)
}
```

I'm getting following error: `Value Forbidden of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject` and this:

```
NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected response code 403 for https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/AAPL?period1=1635962336&period2=1667498336&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true
```

The query is working well. You can try on postman or browser. I also tried different variations like `JsonObjectRequest` or `Method.POST` instead of `GET`. Retrofit also didn't work. It was even working before.

Comment: The response seems to be a CSV file:

content-disposition: attachment; filename=AAPL.csv
content-type: text/csv;charset=utf-8

Is that what your client expects?

Comment: @DavidSoroko - Do you mean the header? I tried setting up the header as you suggested, but I still get the same response. I also added the other exception to the question that i had forgotten before.

Comment: Those headers are in the response (use curl -v to see them). Is your client expects a file in the response?

Comment: No, a string is expected, as indicated by the StringRequest object, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try overriding your header like:

```
override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
    val header = HashMap<String, String>()
    header["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0"
    return header
}
```